# Data is not being saved in database no run time errors

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I'm developing windows forms application in C# with sql server database. I can insert and retrieve data but only in the run time. If I run it again it does not show previously inserted data.

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

Comment: How about you show us the code that you're using to try to insert the data? So far you've only shown us the connection string.

Comment: Any chance to see the SQL you are running?

Comment: public void InsertSub(int SubCode, string SubName, DateTime date, string user)
        {
            string sql1 = "Insert into Inv_Sub_Stores values (" + SubCode + ",'" + SubName + "','" + date + "','" + user + "')";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql1, ConnectionManager.Connection());
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ConnectionManager.Connection().Close();

        }

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `MyDB`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDB;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

You can delete the .mdf and log files in the bin folder, then change the path in the the app.config file to something like this below

connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Path \yourdatabasefile.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"